Javascript add event listner on Input if value change by other button
input event listener fires only when we type something in input, want to fire the event on click of button when values changes from outside


 const currentValue = document.querySelector('#currentValue');
        currentValue.addEventListener('input', function () {
          // This one fires only when we type something in input, want to fire this on click of button when values changes from outside
            console.log("Input alue changed!!");
        });

function myFunction() {
  console.log("Button Clicked..");
  currentValue.value = 3;
}
<input type="text" id="currentValue" value="1"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>



